# ¿Como guardar datos que extraigo de una Base de datos en una array o variables en python?

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un pequeño programa en python que se conecta a una base de datos y extrae todos los datos de una tabla (solo son dos registros) hasta aqui todo bien puede hacerlo sin problemas, ahora mi pregunta es como guardo esos datos que extraje de la DB en variables ya que despues quiero exportar esos datos excel igual desde python este es mi codigo espero me puedan ayudar.

```
import os
import pyodbc
os.system ("cls")
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=COFAF00050328;'
                  'Database=prueba;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM prueba.dbo.Personas')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Comment: puedes usar pandas

Comment: Hola Angel, la pregunta es un poco amplia creo. Si vas a trabajar esos datos y modificarlos antes de pasarlos a un excel, si son muchos datos concuerdo con JackNavaRow, usa [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) que te permite almacenarlos, procesarlos eficientemente y luego exportarlos a un archivo de Excel. Si son pocos crea una lista con `rows = cursor.fetchall()` o `rows = list(cursor)` . Si no vas a modificar los datos para nada, simplemente no los almacenes en ningún lado, itera sobre el cursor y vas guardando cada fila en el excel.